# Digits of powers of $2$ and $3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

> Does there exist a positive power of $2$ whose digits in decimal representation can be rearranged to form a power of $3$?

How do we deal with the last digits of powers of $3$? We know that a power of $3$ ends in $1,3,9,7,$ but how do we deal with the other digits?

Comment: Well, can we show that $2^n$ never has $5$ as a digit?  Since $5^n$ always ends with $5$

Comment: @SimpleArt no we cannot.

Comment: if you're going to edit your question every time you find an example, why are you not asking directly for the set of solutions ?

Comment: The digits of $2^0$ can be "rearranged" (with the identity permutation) to form the digits of $5^0$.

Comment: Changing your question repeatedly as people answer it is somewhat bad form.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see a (naively computed) "probability" that this will eventually occur.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki The original question was trivial, so that's why I changed it.

Comment: how was it trivial !?

Comment: @mercio Because $2^7 = 256$ and $5^4 = 625$.

Comment: That's not trivial.  We had to stumble upon it.  But powers of three is trivial as powers of 3 are divisible by three and have digits that add to multiples of three and powers of 2 do not.  (as per peters answer.)

Comment: @user19405892 Trivial or not, you should not change the question completely after it has been answered. If you really do not want to ask a new question, you should at least keep the original question alive and extend it with an additional question.

Comment: @user19405892 OK, an additional question would be a good compromise. You are likely to get another answer and you do not annoy the answerer of the former question. I do not want to appear rude or offensive, I only want to give a suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answe is no :

If you rearrange the digits of a power of $2$, the digit-sum will not be divisble by $3$, hence the number will not be divisible by $3$. In particular, it will not be a power of $3$.

Comment: D'oh, of course!

Answer (score 4):

> $512 = 2^9$

seems to work fine compared with $125=5^3$

Comment: OP changed the question.

Comment: Hi, since I changed the question, do you mind deleting this answer?

Comment: @user19405892 Instead of editing the question you should just have posted a new one

Comment: "I don't see what's wrong in editing a question".  Then you aren't looking hard enough.  It's a completely different question no and you are wasting the time of all the people reading it and who have gone out of their way to answer your question.  Not to mention it makes you appear a truly ungrateful little punk.  You probably are not one but editing a question and asking people to delete their answers sure make you *look* like one.

Comment: @user19405892 I think his point is nobody wants to waste their time, math or not math. MSE doesn't place a limit on the number of questions you can ask; changing one question into a totally different question obviously turns that time into a waste at no benefit to you or the community as a whole who might care about the answer to the old question, easy or not.

Comment: @AdamHughes Are you still going to leave your answer up as it does not answer the new question?

Comment: @user19405892 look at my user profile, I have over 25k rep, including over 20 questions with over 10 upvotes and hundreds more with positive votes and a very high acceptance rate. I regularly hit the 200 reputation per day limit, if I wanted rep I would just answer another question.